# Aframe - Raycast class filter doesn't update at runtime

Tags: javascript, events, aframe, webvr

I have a scene, that has a set of objects that I want to be selectable at a particular time.

Some of these objects are visible and an some invisible when the application starts.

The visible objects will have the class .clickable, so that I can click on them with the mouse to perform an operation and .nonclickable for the invisible ones.

However, the when i change the class of the objects from .nonclickable to .clickable, the objects remain unchanged and are still clickable.

Even though the objects are now invisible, there are still registering an event if the mouse enters that area.

So is there a way to have the raycast not interact with the objects once the class type has been changed?

__

PS. I had a work around using

evt.originalTarget.setAttribute("[raycaster]", "objects: .nonclickable")

but this only works with firefox, but breaks with chrome.

Thanks for any help inregards to this.

Comment: I think i might have a solution, by giving the elemnt an id of init_ray, then using the document.getElementById, tochange the attribute insead. 'document.getElementById("init_ray").setAttribute("raycaster", "objects: .nothing");'

Comment: Needs more elaboration. Link to working example? FWIW the syntax you provided is incorrect. `evt.target.setAttribute(‘raycaster’, ‘objects: .nonclickable’)` name of component is not right and originalTarget is a [non estandard Firefox only feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets)

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for responsing, you are right  `evt.target` was the solution that I was looking for. I just completely overlooked it in the inspector. I'm not fully sure why it worked in firefox. but now it working as expected. many thanks.

Comment: Turned comment into answer for future reference. Mark as correct if accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided syntax is incorrect. It is:

`evt.target.setAttribute(‘raycaster’, ‘objects: .nonclickable’)`

Name of component is not right and `originalTarget` is a [non standard Firefox only feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets)